# FadeIn FadeOut and why the div moves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

probably is something that I'm missing, but I have a little headache with this.

I'd like to have the "submenu div" align on the right of Show/hide links.

When I load the div is correctly in its place, but when I click to hide/show links, suddenly the div changes the place to the bottom.

BTW, is there any other better way to do this, or this this is good? Also, if I don't what to show the div on the page load, I'm thinking to use .hide() or hidden style, is that ok?

Example http://jsfiddle.net/DH75T/

Thanks in advance

CSS

```
div.inline2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
div.inline {
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $('a#show').click(function() {
    $('div#submenu').fadeIn();
  });

  $('a#hide').click(function() {
    $('div#submenu').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

HTML

```
  <div class="inline2">
    <a href="#" id="show">Show_links</a>
    <a href="#" id="hide">Hide links</a>
  </div>

  <div class="inline" id="submenu">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a><br />
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fadeIn()` adds div style `display: block;` so div shows down to next line

---

Before div was styled `inline-block`

```css
div.inline2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/u2yw7/)</kbd>

Use classes to add effect of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` without moving your div to next line

```css
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#show').click(function () {
        $('div#submenu').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
    });

    $('a#hide').click(function () {
        $('div#submenu').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
    });
});
```

**css**

```css
.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally I've used your solution. And to open the page with the submenu links hidden? beacuse if I toggle to hiden during the load you'll be able to  see the submenu going hide and doesn't look nice..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
  $('a#show').click(function() {
    $('div#submenu').removeClass("none");
  });    
  $('a#hide').click(function() {
    $('div#submenu').addClass("none");
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DH75T/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change only jQuery code :) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  

$('a#show').click(function() {
$( "div#submenu" ).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

$('a#hide').click(function() {
$( "div#submenu" ).animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
});</script>
```